# very basic generic sql (efficiency) principal

Tags: sql, performance, select, join

Which of these 2 SQL statements would take less time in most cases?
1)

```
SELECT table_a.foo,
       table_b.zoo
FROM   table_a,
       table_b
WHERE  table_a.id = table_b.id
       AND table_b.bar = 'something'
```

2)

```
SELECT table_a.foo,
       tableb.zoo
FROM   table_a,
       (SELECT *
        FROM   table_b
        WHERE  bar = 'something') AS tableb
WHERE  table_a.id = tableb.id
```

Or are they the same?
It seems (2) would be faster...

Comment: What Implementation? SQL Server would be the same.

Comment: If you're using something other than MySQL the performance would likely be identical.

Comment: Any DBMS with a sufficiently modern optimizer will execute both statements in the same way. Just look at the execution plan and you'll know. You should however get used to explicit `JOIN`s instead of implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: SQL is a 4G declarative language. You should specify what you want, not how you think the DBMS should get it. Any modern DBMS can execute the above 2 statements in the same way or even other ways that you haven't even thought of at the time of writing the SQL depending on the presence of indexes and other objects such as clusters and materialized views (in the case of an Oracle DBMS).

Comment: PLease please don;t use either! Learn to use explicit joins. Implicit joins were replaced more than 20 years ago, explicit joins better describe what the intent was and are far less subject to things like accidental cross joins. Using implict joins is a SQL antipattern.

Comment: EXPLAIN is your friend.

Comment: 1) I appreciate the comments to use Explain, and measurements  
2) I use postgres but... I'm interested in a principal that applies "in most cases"
3) Many commented that the 2 are the same after optimization. Ok, so that still leaves the question open for when there is no optimization  
4) I realize it's data dependent and that indices are important, but… "in most cases"…   
5) Would the "explicit join" form of both of my queries make any difference? Anyway, I would appreciate it if someone entered the equivalent explicit form of my queries

Answer (score 5):

The other answers and comments are guessing or generalizing.

The real answer is that it depends on several things, including:

- Implementation of SQL optimizer; which brand of RDBMS are you using? MySQL? Microsoft SQL Server? Oracle? You should tag your question with the appropriate brand.
- Table definitions, including relevant indexes.
- Size of tables, and size of the subset of the table matched by the conditions.
- Size of the data relative to the size of the cache.
- etc.

It's true that SQL is *supposed* to be an abstract, declarative language as  @Colin'tHart mentions in a comment. So you're supposed to be able to declare two different queries that will produce the same result, and the RDBMS is supposed to translate that into the optimal way of gathering that data. Fine in theory, but in reality that magic is only as good as the number of cases the software designers implemented code for.

So the very basic generic sql (efficiency) principal you mention in the title of this question should be:

**Measure performance -- don't guess or generalize.**

To try to investigate this further, you should get a report from the SQL optimizer of how it intends to access tables and indexes to achieve your query. Most RDBMS products have some variation of a statement called **EXPLAIN** that allows you to get this report for a given query. If the RDBMS is successful in making this case abstract, the EXPLAIN report should be identical for both example queries you show.

For example, I tried a similar query against a test MySQL database. The EXPLAIN shows that there is an extra step to run a *derived table* subquery, which is then used to look up matching rows.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT c.*, t.* FROM cast_info c 
JOIN ( SELECT * FROM title WHERE title = 'Star Wars') t ON c.movie_id = t.id\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived2>
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 8
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: c
         type: ref
possible_keys: movie_id
          key: movie_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: t.id
         rows: 9
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: title
         type: ref
possible_keys: title
          key: title
      key_len: 152
          ref: const
         rows: 8
        Extra: Using where
```

Doing the plain join without a subquery is a little different, it still searches the same table first, but it doesn't have to treat it as a derived table.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT c.*, t.* FROM cast_info c 
JOIN title t ON c.movie_id = t.id WHERE title = 'Star Wars'\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,title
          key: title
      key_len: 152
          ref: const
         rows: 8
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: c
         type: ref
possible_keys: movie_id
          key: movie_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: imdb.t.id
         rows: 9
        Extra: NULL
```

Using the SQL-89 (comma-style) join syntax is treated identically to the query using `JOIN` syntax:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT c.*, t.* FROM cast_info c, title t 
WHERE c.movie_id = t.id AND title = 'Star Wars'\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,title
          key: title
      key_len: 152
          ref: const
         rows: 8
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: c
         type: ref
possible_keys: movie_id
          key: movie_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: imdb.t.id
         rows: 9
        Extra: NULL
```

This is just the result for MySQL. Another RDBMS' optimizer might behave differently, and its output of EXPLAIN will certainly look different. The point is that you have tools available to you to test the query for its optimization plan for yourself.

The EXPLAIN report is *one* such tool. But EXPLAIN usually only shows you what the optimizer plans to do, without actually running the query. You can also use a **profiler** tool to run the query and get a more precise measure of execution time. What profiler tool is available depends on your brand of RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Neither would be as efficient as this query:

```
SELECT
    table_a.foo,
    table_b.zoo
FROM table_a
JOIN table_b
ON table_a.id = table_b.id
AND table_b.bar = 'something'
```

Notice how the extra condition on tableb is in the join condition, *not* the where clause, which means it is evaluated *as the join is made*, which can avoid adding enormous numbers of rows to the temporary result set.

If it were in the where clause, it would be evaluated *after all joins are made*, because the where clause is a *filter* on the result set.

Comment: I did not downvote, but FWIW most if not all RDBMS optimizers do exactly the same thing internally regardless of whether you use SQL-89 (comma-style) or SQL-92 (`JOIN`) syntax for joins. This was confirmed for eight different RDBMS products in *SQL Performance Tuning* by Peter Gulutzan and Trudy Pelzer.

Comment: @bill that is interesting. I have noticed though that the moving the non-key condition into the join condition gives a big inprovent.

Comment: There might be some specific edge cases, but I encourage you to use EXPLAIN to analyze both forms of query and see how similar they are.

Comment: You are assuming that table_a.id = table_b.id would eliminate more than table_b.bar = 'something'

Answer (score -1):

Query 1 will take less time according to my understanding, because in the 2nd Query

```
SELECT *
        FROM   table_b
        WHERE  bar = 'something'
```

will run first and then it will cross-check with the outer query.